# Input field with a value that persists between sessions

Tags: front-end, inputfield, persistence

Ultimately, I would like to have input field that will remember in front-end its last session value, while its related variable should not be local and should be dynamic.

Input field will be put in a panel and its value will be used elsewhere. After a file is saved and Mathematica is closed and afterwards reopened, I would like to have last value in that field. Value is of list type.

Step by step tries:

1. As in WM documentation, initialization works fine (result is input field with 'value'):

   ```
   Dynamic[x, Initialization :> (x := value)]
   ```
2. When Dynamic is put in input field, initialization doesn't work any more (result is 'x' in input field):

   ```
   InputField[Dynamic[x, Initialization :> (x := value)]]
   ```
3. DynamicModule works, but variable is local (result is input field with 'value'):

   ```
   DynamicModule[{x = value}, InputField[Dynamic[x]]]
   ```

On top of that remains a question how to save 'value' for next time initialization.

Edit:

As suggested, SaveDefinitions were considered. The following works, but has DynamicWrapper hidden.

```
DynamicModule[{x = value}, {InputField[Dynamic[x]], DynamicWrapper["", global = x]},
SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

For me this can be considered as an answer because I can hide DynamicWrapper in Panel easily, but it is not elegant solution or applicable in more constrained environments.

Comment: It looks like [`PersistentValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PersistentValue.html) may be useful for this

Comment: Have you tried using the option SaveDefinitions, e.g., `DynamicModule[{x = value}, InputField[Dynamic[x]], SaveDefinitions -> True]`?

Comment: `PersistentValue` has high WM version requirements (11.1 and updated in 12.0) so I am avoiding it (but considering).